# Windows suggests system information when searching for "what"

Tags: windows-10

I use WhatsApp on my desktop and the quickest way to access it is to search for "what" in the windows search.

But windows instead suggests the System Information app. For whatever reason this has a closer match to "what" than "whatsapp" - windows puts a caption saying Related: "what version of windows". So I keep accidentally opening system information.

Can I get rid of this somehow without completely disabling system information from being searchable in windows search?

Comment: Why not just pin WhatsApp to Start or your taskbar?

Comment: I like using hotkeys / not using the mouse as much as possible

Comment: just pin it to the Nth position on the taskbar and press Win+N (N = 1..9)

Comment: nice, thank you, didn't know about that